# Does a better form exists for the coefficients of this product of power series?

Tags: power-series, closed-form

Let

$$f(a,b,t) = \sqrt{1-at}\sqrt{1-bt}$$

We take the series for $\sqrt{1-at}$ and $\sqrt{1-bt}$ around $t = 0$ and multiply them together to find

$$f(a,b,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}{(1-2k)(1-2n+2k)k!^2 (n-k)!^2}a^k b^{n-k}\,.$$

Can we find some simpler representation of these coefficients? Obviously some sort of closed form would be nice. If we compute the first few terms we have

$$\begin{align*}f(a,b,t)= & \,\,1-\frac{1}{2}(a+b)t-\frac{1}{8}(a-b)^2t^2-\frac{1}{16}(a-b)^2(a+b)t^3\\&-\frac{1}{128}(a-b)^2(5a^2+6ab+5b^2)+\cdots\end{align*}$$

and that's what gave me the inspiration to ask this question. Now let

$$g(a,b,t) = \frac{-8}{(a-b)^2t^2}\left(f(a,b,t)-1+\frac{1}{2}(a+b)t\right)$$

we have the expansion

$$g(a,b,t) = 1+\frac{1}{2}(a+b)t+\frac{1}{16}(5a^2+6ab+5b^2)t^2\\\quad\quad\quad+\frac{1}{32}(7a^3+9a^2b+9ab^2+7b^3)t^3+\cdots$$

which seems to get at the more difficult coefficients. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe $f(a,b,t)=\sqrt{1-(a+b)t+abt^2}$ helps?

Comment: With Hagen's hint it would seem the coefficient of $a^rb^st^m$ equals $$\sum_{\substack{k+\ell=m \\ \ell+u=r \\ k-u=s}} (-1)^{k-\ell}\binom{1/2}{k} \binom{k}{\ell} \binom{k-\ell}{u},$$ although I could have made a simple mistake somewhere. The fact that $$\binom{1/2}{\color{Blue}{k}} \binom{\color{Blue}{k}}{\color{Green}{k-\ell}} \binom{\color{Green}{k-\ell}}{u}$$ cascades as it does might be suggestive for simplifying further.

Comment: Thanks @anon. I'll try it out. How would you get the first representation here? Expand $\sqrt{1-x}$ with $x = (a+b)t+abt^2$ and then expand once more with the binomial theorem?

Comment: Yes, and then expand the powers of $a+b$ after that.

Comment: Your function $g(a,b,t)$ is tabulated in OEIS entry [A120406](https://oeis.org/A120406). A closed form can be obtained from their definition of $T(n,k)$ in COMMENTS and the binomial expression given in FORMULA.

Comment: Thanks for that reference. I'll look into it in more detail later!